# jQuery functions not working after using $(document).click

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, document

All functions stop working after I use for the first time this function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var popbox = '#popbox';

  $(document).click(function(event){
      if(!$(event.target).closest(popbox).length && !$(event.target).hasClass('popper')){
          if($(popbox).is(":visible")){
              $(popbox).hide();
          }
      }
  });
```

For example

```
  $('#ajax').on('click', 'span.popper', function(){
      $('#ajax').off('mouseenter mouseleave mousemove', 'span.popper');
  })
  .on('mouseenter', 'span.popper', popperMouseenter)
  .on('mouseleave', 'span.popper', popperMouseleave)
  .on('mousemove', 'span.popper', function(e){
      popperMousemove(e);   
  });
});
```

does not work anymore. But before clicking outside #popbox everything works fine. Why?

**EDIT: ADDED INFORMATIONS**

When mouse enter a span a div `#popbox` appears (`.show()`) calling ajax data.
This div holds if the user clicks on it.
I want `#popbox` to `.hide()` if the user clicks outside it: this is done by the `$(document).click` function.
But when reentering on `#popbox` nothing is showed nor ajax is called if the user clicked outside calling the `$(document).click` function. Otherwise everything works fine.

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: Can you reproduce this problem at JSFiddle?

Comment: It's a litlle complicated: this script works with AJAX and external editors. I made an edit to my question.

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle with complex sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your problem is you are defining the popbox outside the function.
You can try this. It worked for me.

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    var popbox = $('#popbox');

    if (!popbox.is(e.target) && popbox.has(e.target).length === 0) {
        if ($(popbox).is(":visible")) {
            popbox.hide();
        }
    }
});
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2cr0h98e/)**

Comment: Check the fiddle please

Answer (score 0):

```
Close the bracket

$(document).ready(function(){
  var popbox = '#popbox';

  $(document).click(function(event){
      if(!$(event.target).closest(popbox).length && !$(event.target).hasClass('popper')){
          if($(popbox).is(":visible")){
              $(popbox).hide();
          }
      });**//Here closing barc was missing.**

  });
```